# Using a single subscription variable with BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I use `BehaviorSubject` in my `Angular` app and I get observable to my `Details` component from `DataService` as shown below:

***DataService.ts:***

```
export class DataService {

    private messageTracker = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
    private fileTracker = new BehaviorSubject<any>();

    getMessageTracker(): Observable<any> {
        return this.messageTracker.asObservable();
    }

    getFileTracker(): Observable<any> {
        return this.fileTracker.asObservable();
    }

    //set methods omitted for brevity
}
```

***DetailComponent :***

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

    subscription; //??? Can I use this variable for every subscription below?

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.subscription = this.dataService.getMessageTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {
                //...  
        });

        this.subscription = this.dataService.getFileTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {
            //...
        });
    }
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

My questions are:

**1)** As far as I know, as above, I should create a new `BehaviorSubject` variable for each event e.g. `messageCreateTracker` (for tracking a new message added), `fileCreateTracker` (for tracking a new file added, `messageUpdateTracker` (for tracking a message updated). Is that all true?

**2)** Looking `DetailComponent`, I just used a single `subscription` variable for every subscriptions of `Observables`. Is that a bad approach? Should I create a new subscription variable for each subscriptions in `ngOnInit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer For Query 1:**

It **depends on the developer's coding style**, or how he thought, you can also pass the type of event and data with that, in that case, you will need only one `BehaviorSubject`, like this :

```
this.messageTracker.next({ type : 'create' ,  data });
this.messageTracker.next({ type : 'update' ,  data });
this.messageTracker.next({ type : 'delete' ,  data });
```

But this **can also create a complexity** if it goes large, gain depends on the requirements of the project, **your way is also good**.

---

**Answer For Query 2:**

Basically, you can't handle multiple subscriptions like that it will override the previous one and it will only unsubscribe the last one :

So you can create **multiple variables** for that **OR single array/object** of your subscription and then unsubscribe all :

**With Array :**

```
this.subscription = [];
this.subscription.push(this.dataService.getMessageTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {}));    
this.subscription.push(this.dataService.getFileTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {}));

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.forEach(sub => {
        sub.unsubscribe();
    })
}
```

**With Object :**

```
this.subscription = {};
this.subscription['messageTracker'] = this.dataService.getMessageTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {}));
this.subscription['fileTracker'] = this.dataService.getFileTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {}));

this.subscription['fileTracker'].unsubscribe(); // <--- You can also do
delete this.subscription['fileTracker']; // <--- then dont forgot to remove, or will throw error in ngOnDestroy

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for(key in this.subscription) {
      this.subscription[key].unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanations, voted up. For **Q1**, it's OK I will continue to use my approach above :) For **Q2**, which one would you prefer between **multiple variables** or **single array/object**? And I think the latter seems better, but if I use it (single array/object), may it cause complexity? Could you please clarify me a little bit more?

Comment: @hexadecimal, would prefer  single array/object, not there is no complexity until you want to unsubscribe specific one.

Comment: For array `this.subscription = [];` , for Object `this.subscription = {};`

Answer (score 0):

though marked answer is well explained, I want to share some of my thoughts here.

> **Question 1**

- It is better to create new **[`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)** object when you consider code maintenance and readability.
- Instantly notify anything that is subscribed to the **`BehaviorSubject`** when the data changes. This will give you more complexity if you try to deal with different type of data with one object.

> **Question 2**

As @Vivek pointed out  your `this.subscription` will be override the last subscription on every new subscribe.

for this you can use **[`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html)** class,

> Represents a disposable resource, such as the execution of an Observable. A Subscription has one important method, unsubscribe, that takes no argument and just disposes the resource held by the subscription.

you can use this in two ways,

- you can directly push the subscription to Subscription Array

  ```
   subscriptions:Subscription[] = [];

   ngOnInit(): void {

     this.subscription.push(this.dataService.getMessageTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {
              //...  
     }));

     this.subscription.push(this.dataService.getFileTracker().subscribe((param: any) => {
          //...
      }));
   }

   ngOnDestroy(){
      // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
      this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
    }
  ```
- using **`add()`** of `Subscription`

  ```
  subscriptions = new Subscription();

  this.subscriptions.add(subscribeOne);
  this.subscriptions.add(subscribeTwo);

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
  ```

A **`Subscription`** can hold child subscriptions and safely unsubscribe them all. This method handles possible errors (e.g. if any child subscriptions are null).

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. This is also another great application and completes the previous one. I was just reading another useful article pointing out the same issue on [Angular Best Practice: Unsubscribing (RxJS Observables)](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-best-practice-unsubscribing-rxjs-observables/) and now I have been totally clarified. Many thanks again, voted up ;)

Comment: nice article.. n glad to help you :)