# Doing interval properly with Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using the lastest version of Angular and I'm looking for the best way to create and clear an interval.

And I can't find any example of code for clearing an interval.

My component is like this at the moment :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from '../api.service';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-play',
  templateUrl: './play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./play.component.scss']
})
@Injectable()
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private api: APIService;
  private timer: Observable<Number>;

  constructor(_api: APIService) {
    this.api = _api;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = interval(1000);
    this.timer.subscribe(() => this.api.status().subscribe(status => console.log(status)));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // How to clear interval here ? 
  }

}
```

How am I supposed to destroy my interval in the `ngOnDestroy`  method ? If I don't destroy it, the interval keep running every time i create a new component.

Comment: Try this `this.timer.unsubscribe();` in `ngOnDestroy()` method.

Comment: `unsubscribe` does not exist in `Observable`

Comment: Refer to @ganesh045's answer It will resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, use **[`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html)**

```
  subscription = Subscription[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = interval(1000);
    this.subscription.push(this.timer.subscribe(() => 
        this.api.status().subscribe(status => console.log(status)))
       );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     // unsubscribe subscription here
     this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

for more about **`Subscription`** check **[`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57584718/9764133)** which is explained in detail..

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: `this.subscription.unsubscribe();` will do unsubscribe all the Subscription objects which is added in `Subscription[]` array? Or we should specify a particular index of the array like `this.subscription[index].unsubscribe();`?

Comment: It will `unsubscribe()`all the subscriptions held by the `subscription`. If you want to unsubscribe by the index of it, you can but that will be complex when you consider Observable execution time is not specific.. ;)

Comment: have look here for more.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57584718/9764133 and http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html

Comment: ok, so `unsubscrib()` method also check for child subscriptions too, nice thanks for the details.. ;)